# How to add 'date_add()' in adonis js query builder

Tags: adonis.js

I am trying to convert a row sql query. Here is my original row query that I want to run

```
select * from sales WHERE updated_at BETWEEN 
  date_add('2018-10-24', INTERVAL -10 HOUR) 
and 
  date_add('2018-10-25', INTERVAL -10 HOUR)
```

I want to add this date_add functionality into this query

```
Sale.query().whereBetween('updated_at',[data.date1,data.date2])
```

.getSum('totalAmount')

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a **whereRaw**, your query will be the next

```
Sale.query().whereRaw('updated_at BETWEEN date_add('2018-10-24', INTERVAL -10 HOUR) and date_add('2018-10-25', INTERVAL -10 HOUR'))
```

Comment: seems I have to use raw query :) Thanks buddy